# Link not prepending to all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code below that consist of a Tab with some data and a button. Whenever the user clicks on the button it will prepend this link `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` into my img src.

The problem is i'm not sure why it is only prepending to the first image only and not all of it. All of my image id is the same im not sure why this is happening.

This is the function

```
function clickme() {
    $('#imageID').attr('src', function(index, src) {
      return 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + src;
    });
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated thanks.

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["first-Name"]: "John",
  ["last-Name"]: "Doe",
  ["age"]: 21,
  ["hobbies"]: ["football", "swimming", "dancing"],
  ["gender"]: "Male",
  ["person-desc"]: "<br />Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky <br />boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person2 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Paul",
  ["last-Name"]: "Logan",
  ["age"]: 22,
  ["hobbies"]: ["camping", "sleeping", "eating"],
  ["gender"]: "Male",
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
};

personArr.push(person, person2);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var name = document.createElement('h4');
  var gender = document.createElement('h4');
  var desc = document.createElement('p');
  var hobb = document.createElement('div');
  var age = document.createElement('age');
  var logo = document.createElement('div');
  var show = document.createElement('div');

  var hobbies = '';
  $.each(person['hobbies'], function(index) {
    hobbies += ('<div>' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>');
  });
  hobb.className = "hide";
  logo.className = "thumb";
  age.className = "square";
  hobb.innerHTML = hobbies;
  age.innerHTML = `${person['age']} Age`;
  name.textContent = `Name : ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
  desc.textContent = `${person['person-desc']}`;
  show.innerHTML = `<a href="#">Show more</a>`;
  gender.innerHTML = `Gender: ${person['gender']}`;
  logo.innerHTML = `<img id ="imageID" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/4/49/Ash_Pikachu.png/250px-Ash_Pikachu.png" height="auto" width="70">`;

  frag.appendChild(name);
  frag.appendChild(gender);
  frag.appendChild(age);
  frag.appendChild(logo);
  frag.appendChild(desc);
  frag.appendChild(hobb);
  frag.appendChild(show);

});
parent.appendChild(frag);

//<---------------------------------------------- TAB FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide').hide();

  $("a").click(function() {
    $('.hide').toggle();

  });

});

function clickme() {
  $('#imageID').attr('src', function(index, src) {
    return 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + src;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.size {
  width: 50%;
}

a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #81C784;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #81C784;
}

.thumb {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #90A4AE;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="clickme();">Click Me!</button>
  <div class="size">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
    </div>

    <div id="People" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="line1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because an ID can only be used once and not multiple times. Switch the ID to a class and your problem should be gone.

Answer (score 3):

Like I stated in my comment, you're using an `ID` (which can only be assigned to a single element, like a student ID) where you should be using a `class` (which can have more elements, like a class in a school).

Some more information on `ID`'s here in the [MDN Element ID documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and the `class` [documentation as well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class).

```js
var personArr = [];
var person = {
  ["first-Name"]: "John",
  ["last-Name"]: "Doe",
  ["age"]: 21,
  ["hobbies"]: ["football", "swimming", "dancing"],
  ["gender"]: "Male",
  ["person-desc"]: "<br />Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky <br />boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin."
};
var person2 = {
  ["first-Name"]: "Paul",
  ["last-Name"]: "Logan",
  ["age"]: 22,
  ["hobbies"]: ["camping", "sleeping", "eating"],
  ["gender"]: "Male",
  ["person-desc"]: "Bacon ipsum dolor amet short loin doner tail meatloaf hamburger jerky boudin picanha shankle turducken prosciutto cow kielbasa tenderloin. "
};

personArr.push(person, person2);
console.log(personArr);

var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('line1')[0];
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

personArr.forEach((person, i) => {
  var name = document.createElement('h4');
  var gender = document.createElement('h4');
  var desc = document.createElement('p');
  var hobb = document.createElement('div');
  var age = document.createElement('age');
  var logo = document.createElement('div');
  var show = document.createElement('div');

  var hobbies = '';
  $.each(person['hobbies'], function(index) {
    hobbies += ('<div>' + person['hobbies'][index] + '</div>');
  });
  hobb.className = "hide";
  logo.className = "thumb";
  age.className = "square";
  hobb.innerHTML = hobbies;
  age.innerHTML = `${person['age']} Age`;
  name.textContent = `Name : ${person['first-Name']} ${person['last-Name']}`;
  desc.textContent = `${person['person-desc']}`;
  show.innerHTML = `<a href="#">Show more</a>`;
  gender.innerHTML = `Gender: ${person['gender']}`;
  logo.innerHTML = `<img class="imageClass" src="https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/4/49/Ash_Pikachu.png/250px-Ash_Pikachu.png" height="auto" width="70">`;

  frag.appendChild(name);
  frag.appendChild(gender);
  frag.appendChild(age);
  frag.appendChild(logo);
  frag.appendChild(desc);
  frag.appendChild(hobb);
  frag.appendChild(show);

});
parent.appendChild(frag);

//<---------------------------------------------- TAB FUNCTION ------------------------------------------------------->
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hide').hide();

  $("a").click(function() {
    $('.hide').toggle();

  });

});

function clickme() {
  $('.imageClass').attr('src', function(index, src) {
    return 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + src;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.line1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.size {
  width: 50%;
}

a.morelink {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.morecontent span {
  display: none;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0;
}

.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #81C784;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #81C784;
}

.thumb {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #90A4AE;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<style>

</style>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="clickme();">Click Me!</button>
  <div class="size">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'People')" id="defaultOpen">People</button>
    </div>

    <div id="People" class="tabcontent">
      <div class="line1">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>

<script>
</script>
```